# PHP user_registered, possible to find date/time for existing users?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of users in a table on my admin page on my PHP website. I wanted to see the creation date for each user.

I was able to add `user_registered` to my DB in phpMyAdmin. This allows me to see creation dates for new users (moving forward), but is there a way to show dates for existing users - the ones added before I added `user_registered`?

Comment: Unless you have a log somewhere else, otherwise you can't retrieve the date a row is inserted into your database.

Comment: Goot to know! Makes sense! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are storing date in your table while saving user data then you will be able to fetch the dates otherwise you cant get it

Comment: I wasn't at the time, so guess I can't get something that doesn't exist. Thanks, it makes sense.